# Read specific columns and rows from .text

Tags: vb.net

Well, I need to read columns and rows from a .txt
and get only the data I need.

Example: The file "sample.txt" has the following content

C = Columns

R = Rows

```
  C1  C2 C3
```

R1   0     0  0       3694440008091082330089 ALBINA HANSEN OF OLMEDO 00000075000000022091401520117873

I need the following data for each row:

000369444000809108**2330089**  **ALBINA HANSEN DE OLMEDO**       000000**75000**0000**220914**0**1**520117873

(The series of numbers and letters above the value of the first line)

- First Value: Starts at C19 to C25 (2330089)
- Second Value: Starts at C28 to C50 (ALBINA HANSEN DE OLMEDO)
- Third Value: Starts at C64 to C68 (75000)
- Fourth Value: Starts at C73 to C78 (220914)
- Fifth Value: It is only the C80 column (1)

And I need to display the data in a message box:

I have the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fileReader As String
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\cogentvaio\Desktop\Banco Itau\TXT-FOMENTO ANGELIUS.txt")
        MsgBox(fileReader)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This allows me to read the entire contents of .txt

Hopefully you can help me with this, I'm learning to program in vb.net.

---

I'll show you my code, I can not see the boundaries made with ​​substrinng, I used the code you suggested,

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\cogentvaio\Desktop\Banco Itau\ejemplo\-TXT-ITAU ANGELIUS.txt")
    Dim line As String
    For Each line In fileReader
        If line.Length > 80 Then
            Dim c1 = line.Substring(18, 7)
            Dim c2 = line.Substring(28, 50)
            Dim c3 = line.Substring(64, 68)
            Dim c4 = line.Substring(73, 78)
            Dim c5 = line.Substring(80)



        End If
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(fileReader)


End Sub
```

End Class

And what I got was this

[IMAGE_PHOTO](http://subefotos.com/ver/?d0e389b6d1f3c431f478bbf54e2dcce0o.jpg)

I don't know where is my mistake

Comment: Do you have only one row or there are many rows?

Comment: check out [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) and how to [concatenate strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx)

Comment: I have many rows to rows that have vary per file, this particular file has 32 rows

Comment: Perhaps [How to: Read From Fixed-width Text Files in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would help.

Answer (score 0):

[string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend here. This method extracts substring from a string starting from a char index and getting back the requested number of chars (length). Also remember that an array (a string is an array of chars) starts always at index zero, so your values Cx values should be decremented by one.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Instead of ReadAllText, use ReadAllLines to have your input splitted in an array of strings
    Dim fileReader = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(......)

    for each line in fileReader

       ' To avoid nasty exceptions be sure that the line is at least 81 chars long
       if line.Length > 80 Then
          Dim c1 = line.Substring(18, 7)
          Dim c2 = line.Substring(27, 23)
          Dim c3 = line.Substring(63, 5)
          Dim c4 = line.Substring(72, 6)
          Dim c5 = line.Substring(79, 1)

          .... process these values....
          .... for example ....
          Dim newLine = string.Join(" ", c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
          MessageBox.Show(newLine)

       End if
    Next
End Sub
```

This changes takes a line, extract the part and creates a new string with only the parts required joined together with a space. Then prints out this new text. Of course, you want a join of all the rows with these subparts you need to add the newLine variable to a `List( Of String)` an then do a final join of the single rows

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Instead of ReadAllText, use ReadAllLines to have your input splitted in an array of strings
    Dim fileReader = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(......)
    Dim subText = New StringBuilder()
    for each line in fileReader
        if line.Length > 80 Then
          ....

          Dim newLine = string.Join(" ", c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
          subText.Add(newLine)
       End if
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, subText))
```

However your indexes doesn't seem to correctly point to the data required. 
This substring extraction seems to find correctly your data

```
  Dim c1 = line.Substring(18, 7)
  Dim c2 = line.Substring(26, 23)
  Dim c3 = line.Substring(56, 5)
  Dim c4 = line.Substring(65, 6)
  Dim c5 = line.Substring(72, 1)
```

Comment: Please, add your editing to your original question text. (use the Edit link button) Possibly explaining better what your output should be

Comment: ReadAllLines it's a library from System.IO ? because i can't use that, i can only choose ReadAllText and ReadAllBytes... Thanks for your patience

Comment: Yes [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) is from System.IO. It is available from NET Framework 2.0. I will fix the answer

Comment: The problem in your updated code is that you still show the original string. In the updated answer I have shown how to extract substrings from the original line and with these substrings created a new string with only the parts in your requirements.